# Program keeps getting segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, codeblocks

Coding this in CodeBlocks, this program keeps getting a seg fault. Could anyone help?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "include/hugeint.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HugeInt h("123");

    return 0;
}
```

my HugeInt Class (whats relevant), stores very large integers as an array of integers

```
class HugeInt
{
public:
    HugeInt(string);
private:
    DynArray dyn;
    //HugeInt& reverse();
    int size;
};

HugeInt::HugeInt(string input)
{
    string digits = input;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < digits.length(); i++){
        dyn.add(digits.at(i) - 48);
    }
    size = dyn.size();
}
```

my dynamic array class of integers

```
class DynArray
{
public:
    DynArray();
    ~DynArray();
private:
    int length;
    int *arr;   //points to this array
    int nextIndex;
};

DynArray::DynArray() {
    arr = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        arr[i] = 0;
    length = 10;
    nextIndex = 0; }

DynArray::~DynArray()
{
    delete [] arr;
}

int DynArray::size(){
    return nextIndex;
}

void DynArray::add(int val) {
     int *newArr;
     if (nextIndex == length) {
         length = length + 10;
         newArr = new int[length];
         for (int i = 0; i < nextIndex; i++)
            newArr[i] = arr[i];
         for (int j = nextIndex; j < length; j++)
            newArr[j] = 0;
         delete [] arr;
         arr = newArr;
     }
     arr[nextIndex++] = val;
}
```

Edit: I commented delete [] arr; out and it still seg faults :/

Edit2: OK so the code works if main is as follows. Can Anyone explain why please?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "include/hugeint.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string in = "1234";
    HugeInt h(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is `DynArray::add` implementation?

Comment: My guess is an array of slipping out of bounds somewhere

Comment: Where is it getting this seg fault? Also, you need to follow the rule of three/five if you aren't.

Comment: Have you tried inserting print statements to isolate the location of the segfault, or run it through gdb?

Comment: @chris its getting a segfault in between HugeInt h("123"); and return 0;. I've ran a debugger and it goes through the constructer fine. Also what is the rule of three/five?

Comment: You've got the code for the implementation of `HugeInt h("123");`, whereabouts in there does it happen?

Comment: @user2230341: So it looks like it is crashing in DynArray destructor. Can you show us that implementation as well?

Comment: @user2230341 Your `HugeInt` class seems to think that `DynArray` has a `size()` function.

Comment: @DrewDormann sorry i didnt post it, but it does have a size function. I will post the destructor and size now

Comment: With the code you have posted, I have compiled it and not found a seg fault.

Comment: I can confirm that.  When I add the missing `size()` and `add()` declarations to `DynArray`, the posted code runs without error.  Although **copying a DynArray will cause problems** as it violates the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: could you just try this - remove the code inside HugeInt constructor, write an empty constructor, then put that code to construct HugeInt in a init(string) function, and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to initialize the DynArray in the HugeInt constructor before you start using the DynArray add() method. You didn't include the add method in the code but if it does what I imagine it does, you may have not constructed the DynArray object before using it, thus the seg fault.

Comment: If it's not explicitly initialized, it will be default-initialized.  I think it's okay.

Comment: It will be default-constructed as is.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted compiles and runs without error.

I can speculate that problems are happening elsewhere because `DynArray` does not satisfy the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29).

Currently, if a `DynArray` is copied in any way, that copy will hold the same pointer to the same `int *arr`.

And when that copy is destroyed, so is the array used by all the other copies.

Comment: Can you take a look at my second edit above? Why does it work that way with no seg fault but if I try to pass the string directly as a parameter it seg faults?

Comment: @user2230341 If you're getting segfaults either way, I suspect that the code in your question isn't the complete code you're running to get the segfault.